# OpenShift Kestral causing Socket Hangup error

Tags: c#, .net-core, wso2, openshift

We have containerized .NET Core application and running in OpenShift.

While running our application from UI we are seeing an error

> Underlying connection was closed

Our API is registered with WSO2 and when I run our application using WSO2 gateway through PostMan I see SocketHang Up Error. Below is the error Log

```
ID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,341] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Content-Length header already present {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
                  at org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent.process(ResponseContent.java:101)
                  at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:139)
                  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceResponse.start(SourceResponse.java:179)
                  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler.responseReady(SourceHandler.java:310)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:309)
                  at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.produceOutput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:127)
                  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:87)
                  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onOutputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:39)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:150)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:180)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
                  at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,342]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Writer null when calling informWriterError {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,342] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Unexpected I/O error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
                  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:270)
                  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:461)
                  at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.sendEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.

TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << HTTP/1.1 204 No Content {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << Date: Fri, 12 Nov 2021 12:07:17 GMT {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << Server: Kestrel {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << Content-Length: 0 {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << Set-Cookie: cd1550ebc2ca7854f34f209e62d8deed=a483899cdd89e134e6a0fe6a0f3209f6; path=/; HttpOnly {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,334] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-14 << Cache-control: private {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [] [] [2021-11-12 20:07:17,341] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Content-Length header already present {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
                  at org.apache.http.protocol.ResponseContent.process(ResponseContent.java:101)
```

Main method in the API

```
[HttpGet("Settings/{identifier}/Timestamp")]
public async Task<ActionResult<DateTimeOffset?>> MethodName(string identifier, CancellationToken token)
{
    return await _service.MethodName(identifier, token);
}

public async Task<DateTimeOffset?> MethodName(string username, string identifier, CancellationToken token)
{
    // code the get userSetting from DB
    return userSetting?.somevariable.WithTimeZone(TimeZone);
}

public static DateTimeOffset WithTimeZone(this DateTime time, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
{
    var offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(time);
              
    time = time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified ? time
                            : new DateTime(time.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    
    return time - DateTime.MaxValue > offset
                        ? DateTimeOffset.MaxValue.ToOffset(offset)
                        : new DateTimeOffset(time, offset);
}
```

Below are the possible causes we analyzed

- This API during sometime returns 204 No Content
- Also backend returning a header called Content-Length:0
- This error is caused only when our app is running on OpenShift. In IIS it works fine.

Is it possible to remove the `Content-Length` from the response?

Are there any other causes for this Socket hangup error?

Comment: On Further analysis we found that this is because of Content-Length Header that is causing the issue which is sent by Kestrel server, is there anyway we could remove the header. I tried specifying in the webconfg but it des not work.